# Exception is thrown with Mockito but it is not caught in JUnit

Tags: java, testing, exception, junit, mockito

I have a problem with a test case and cannot pass through it, tried to change some things but in any case the result is the same. I am pretty new to Mockito and to this kind of tests - so cannot understand what may be wrong.

Tried to do this way with a `try catch` block

```
@Test
public void shouldFailToRead_URLFileNotFound() throws IOException {

  URLConnection urlConnection = mock(URLConnection.class);
  fakedUrlStreamHandler.addConnection(URL_FILE_NOT_FOUND, urlConnection);

  FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException = new FileNotFoundException("There is no such a file " + URL_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
  when(urlConnection.getInputStream()).thenThrow(fileNotFoundException);

  try {
    fileUpdater.downloadFile(fileUpdateListener, URL_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
    fail("Was expecting a RuntimeException with FileNotFoundException");
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    assertThat(e.getCause(), equalTo(fileNotFoundException));
  }
}
```

The method that checks if an URL is alive

```
private boolean isUrlFileExists(final URL urlToDownload) {
  try {
    URLConnection connection = urlToDownload.openConnection();
    connection.getInputStream();
    return true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    error("There is no file at " + urlToDownload + ". No Connection: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

The line with `fileUpdater.downloadFile` have a nested call of methods until it get to `isUrlFileExists`.

Tried to do using `expected` keyword

```
(expected = FileNotFoundException.class)
```

Also tried it with @Rule annotation

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();

exceptionRule.expect(FileNotFoundException.class);
```

---

In any case I get the same error message

```
Exception in thread "FileDownloadThread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: There is no such a file http://somehost.com/download/file-not-found.zip
    at com.files.impl.FileUpdater$DownloadWorker.isUrlFileExists(FileUpdater.java:263)
    at com.files.impl.FileUpdater$DownloadWorker.makeDownloadAttempt(FileUpdater.java:285)
    at com.files.impl.FileUpdater$DownloadWorker.run(FileUpdater.java:324)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: There is no such a file http://somehost.com/download/file-not-found.zip
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.files.impl.FileUpdater$DownloadWorker.isUrlFileExists(FileUpdater.java:258)
    ... 2 more

java.lang.AssertionError: Was expecting a RuntimeException with FileNotFoundException
```

So in the end exception is thrown but it cannot be caught in my Test case, what I do wrong in here?

---

Originally tried to write the test this way, and register a `URLStreamHandlerFactory` for that using this [post](https://claritysoftware.co.uk/mocking-javas-url-with-mockito/#:%7E:text=Mocking%20URL%20with%20mockito&text=java.-,net.,passed%20in%20as%20a%20dependency.) as an example, I am using Mockito 1.6 and locked in to this version.

Comment: Your exception is being thrown on a different thread.

Comment: @tgdavies is there a chance I can get it to work another way? do you have an advice?

Comment: How is the caller of `fileUpdater.downloadFile()` meant to determine that there was an error downloading the file? That's what you want to test, not whether you see an exception on the calling thread.

Comment: All of this methods in the chain return void and there is not much logic added, if the file is ok to download then this info is added to a listener, then it notifies other services that the file is ready to download. In this chain I have to test the wrong links that may be sent to it.

Comment: So you need to verify whether the expected method has been called on the listener. You have a mock `fileUpdateListener`.

Comment: You catch the exception in your test. How is JUnit supposed to catch something that's already been caught?